# How to add a successive index numbers to unique values in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

This is an array I have:

```
var arr1 = [
    { ModuleID : 'one', ModuleValue : 'valueX'},
    { ModuleID : 'one', ModuleValue : 'valueV'},
    { ModuleID : 'one', ModuleValue : 'valueE'},
    { ModuleID : 'one', ModuleValue : 'valueY'},
    { ModuleID : 'two', ModuleValue : 'valueZ'},
    { ModuleID : 'two', ModuleValue : 'valueB'},
    { ModuleID : 'two', ModuleValue : 'valueA'}
];
```

I would like to add a successive "index" number to my array based on the ModuleID, like this:

```
var arr2 = [
    { ModuleID : 'one', ModuleValue : 'valueX', index : 0},
    { ModuleID : 'one', ModuleValue : 'valueV', index : 1},
    { ModuleID : 'one', ModuleValue : 'valueE', index : 2},
    { ModuleID : 'one', ModuleValue : 'valueY', index : 3},
    { ModuleID : 'two', ModuleValue : 'valueZ', index : 0},
    { ModuleID : 'two', ModuleValue : 'valueB', index : 1},
    { ModuleID : 'two', ModuleValue : 'valueA', index : 2}
];
```

So far I have came up with this code:

```
var arr2 = [];
var index = 0;


for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; ++i) {
        if (i < arr1.length && arr1[i].ModuleID = arr1[i+1].ModuleID ) {
            index = index + 1;
        } else {
            index = 0;
        };
    arr2.push({ModuleID: arr1[i].ModuleID, ModuleValue: arr1[i].ModuleValue, index: index});
};
```

However it resets the successive number at last value of the ModuleID instead of the first value:

```
var arr2 = [
    { ModuleID : 'one', ModuleValue : 'valueX', index : 1},
    { ModuleID : 'one', ModuleValue : 'valueV', index : 2},
    { ModuleID : 'one', ModuleValue : 'valueE', index : 3},
    { ModuleID : 'one', ModuleValue : 'valueY', index : 0},
    { ModuleID : 'two', ModuleValue : 'valueZ', index : 1},
    { ModuleID : 'two', ModuleValue : 'valueB', index : 2},
    { ModuleID : 'two', ModuleValue : 'valueA', index : 3}
];
```

How can I improve my code?

Comment: Is it possible to have another `ModuleID:'one'` object after `'two'`? Or is it always sorted by `ModuleID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let idx = 0;
arr.map((item, i) => {
    if(i == 0 || arr[i].ModuleID != arr[i-1].ModuleID) 
        idx = 0;
    else 
        idx++;
  item['index'] = idx; 
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much this works. Now will try to get my head around it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could take a hash table for the group wise indices.

```js
var array = [{ ModuleID: 'one', ModuleValue: 'valueX' }, { ModuleID: 'one', ModuleValue: 'valueV' }, { ModuleID: 'one', ModuleValue: 'valueE' }, { ModuleID: 'one', ModuleValue: 'valueY' }, { ModuleID: 'two', ModuleValue: 'valueZ' }, { ModuleID: 'two', ModuleValue: 'valueB' }, { ModuleID: 'two', ModuleValue: 'valueA' }],
    result = array.map(
        (c => o => ({ ...o, index: (c[o.ModuleID] ??= 0, c[o.ModuleID]++) }))
        ({})
    );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the array and check the value of `ModuleID` and depending on that value, add an `index` property with a value of one of two possible counters that then increment. The if/then logic could be done more compactly, but I used `switch` here in case additional `ModuleID` values are added later that also need to be checked for.

```js
var arr1 = [
    { ModuleID : 'one', ModuleValue : 'valueX'},
    { ModuleID : 'one', ModuleValue : 'valueV'},
    { ModuleID : 'one', ModuleValue : 'valueE'},
    { ModuleID : 'one', ModuleValue : 'valueY'},
    { ModuleID : 'two', ModuleValue : 'valueZ'},
    { ModuleID : 'two', ModuleValue : 'valueB'},
    { ModuleID : 'two', ModuleValue : 'valueA'}
];

let a = 0;
let b = 0;

arr1.forEach(function(obj){
  switch (obj.ModuleID) {
    case "one":
      obj.index = a++;
      break;
    case "two":
      obj.index = b++;
      break;
  }
});

console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr2 = [];
var index = 0;
 var transition = false;
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; ++i) {
    if (i < arr1.length && arr1[i].ModuleID = arr1[i+1].ModuleID ) {
        index = index + 1;
    } else {
        transition = true;index = index + 1;
    };
arr2.push({ModuleID: arr1[i].ModuleID, ModuleValue: arr1[i].ModuleValue, index: index});                                         
if(transition){ 
 index=0;
transition = false;
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

is that what you want to do?

```js
var arr1 = [
         {ModuleID: 'one', ModuleValue: 'valueX'},
         {ModuleID: 'one', ModuleValue: 'valueV'},
         {ModuleID: 'one', ModuleValue: 'valueE'},
         {ModuleID: 'one', ModuleValue: 'valueY'},
         {ModuleID: 'two', ModuleValue: 'valueZ'},
         {ModuleID: 'two', ModuleValue: 'valueB'},
         {ModuleID: 'two', ModuleValue: 'valueA'}
    ];
    
    function setIndex (item, idx) {
    
       arr1 [idx] .index = idx + 1
    }
    
    arr1.forEach (setIndex)
    
    console.log ("code changed")
    console.log (arr1)
```

This generated is result

```
[
  {
    "ModuleID": "one",
    "ModuleValue": "valueX",
    "index": 1
  },
  {
    "ModuleID": "one",
    "ModuleValue": "valueV",
    "index": 2
  },
  {
    "ModuleID": "one",
    "ModuleValue": "valueE",
    "index": 3
  },
  {
    "ModuleID": "one",
    "ModuleValue": "valueY",
    "index": 4
  },
  {
    "ModuleID": "two",
    "ModuleValue": "valueZ",
    "index": 5
  },
  {
    "ModuleID": "two",
    "ModuleValue": "valueB",
    "index": 6
  },
  {
    "ModuleID": "two",
    "ModuleValue": "valueA",
    "index": 7
  }
]
```

Comment: No, that's not what the OP wants.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but indeed not what I was looking for as these index numbers continue.